# submit form into external server, results in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have task to do.
I'm building page, multisearch system.
User will input name and select option.
depending on chosen option will be submitted form to specific supplier with request. In return I will get their list in there page. Unfortunately I can't use API to do this. So I try do this old way.

I try PHP with ajax etc but no success. I don't know how to push result from POST into iframe. Be nice if I could modify DOM, change/remove not needed elements of page. When I was using javascript/jquery I get CORS orgin problem.

My code is at moment in main file but later will move it to separated files.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
      <?php
        if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] != "POST" ) {
            $self = $_SERVER[ "PHP_SELF" ];
            ?>
    <form id="search_form" method="post" action="<?php echo $self; ?>" role="form">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input id="companyname" type="text" name="company_name">
          <select id="country" name="country">
        <option value="maine">Maine</option>
      </select>
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <?php 
        }else{
            $company_name = $_POST["company_name"];
            $country = $_POST["country"];

            switch($country){
                case "maine":
                     echo '<script>console.log("maine")</script>';
                    $url = 'https://icrs.informe.org/nei-sos-icrs/ICRS';
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $company_name);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec( $ch );   
//              echo '<script>$("#search_form").bind("submit", function() {
// $.ajax({
//   type     : "POST",
//   cache    : false,
//   url      : "https://icrs.informe.org/nei-sos-icrs/ICRS",
//   data     : {WAISqueryString:  $("company_name")},
//   success  : function() {  $("#myIframe").attr("src", "data.responseText") }
// });
// return false;
//});</script>';
                    break;
            }

        }?>
  </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-12" style="height:100vh">
      <div id="frame" style="height: 100vh"><iframe id="myIframe" scrolling="no"></iframe> </div>
    </div>
```

Your help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with JSONP?

Comment: I have read about this, but I don't found information how to deal with respond.